# Where can i find using System.Web.Helpers and System.Web.Script.Serialization both not exist?

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces, .net-4.5

I added in the top of my new class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Helpers;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
```

And getting not exist red line under: Helpers and under Script
I tried to add a reference of System.Web but it didn't help.

I'm using .net 4.5

I'm trying to use this code in this link:

[Video Information](http://codingstill.com/2013/01/getting-video-information-from-youtube-and-vimeo/)

But missing this namespaces.

Comment: you can find it here first by reading the documentation [MSDN System.Web.Helpers NameSpace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers(v=vs.111).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By checking random types from these namespaces on MSDN, you would discover that `System.Web.Helpers` is in **System.Web.WebPages.dll** assembly and `System.Web.Script.Serialization` is in **System.Web.Extensions.dll** assembly.